# Importing Maven child projects issue using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

When I'm trying to import a Maven Project as Parent with child projects in eclipse (Screenshot 1) I got the child projects under the parent project (Screenshot 2). In this case the maven project is not workig properly.

However I'm would that each child project appears seperatly as Maven Projects in the workspace.

**Screenshot 1:**

[image]

**Screenshot 2**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the Projet Explorer View, I switched the `Projects Presentation` from `Hierarchical` to `Flat` like shown in the screenshot below :

[image]